# LaTeX is not centering my figures whatever is written in code

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment

I cannot center my figures. I tried it in different ways. But all of them are ignored and the image is shown with a left align on the page with a large space on the top of the image.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[natwidth=1200,natheight=898,width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\caption{Result of}
\label{fig:maxMinPedometer10result}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[natwidth=1200,natheight=898,width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Result of}
\label{fig:maxMinPedometer10result}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[natwidth=1200,natheight=898,width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Result of}
\label{fig:maxMinPedometer10result}
\end{figure}    
\end{center}
```

My preamble:

```
\ProvidesPackage{preamblestyle}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Zum Laden von Grafiken
\usepackage{multicol} % Multi-Spalten Layout
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{objectset=centering}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=bottom} 
\newfloatcommand{ftabbox}{table}[\nocapbeside][\FBwidth] 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating}%rotation i.e. tables
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1~#2  \&  \tablename~\thetable}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    tabsize=2,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{black}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{sh_comment}{rgb}{0.12, 0.38, 0.18 }
\definecolor{sh_keyword}{rgb}{0.37, 0.08, 0.25}
\definecolor{sh_string}{rgb}{0.06, 0.10, 0.98}
\definecolor{slightely-gray}{HTML}{f0f0f5}

\lstset {
 frame=single,
  language=JAVA,
  basicstyle=\tiny,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{sh_keyword},
  commentstyle=\color{sh_string}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    backgroundcolor = \color{slightely-gray}
}

\newcommand{\lstJava}[1]    {\lstinline[language=Java,breaklines=true,basicstyle= \listingsfontinline]$#1$}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{makecell}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\hyphenchar\font `\- }
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have no errors in my file. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Most likely off-topic, but `hyperref` and `cleveref` should be loaded at the end of the preamble, not somewhere in the middle of it ;-) In addition: Provide a compilable document, not disrupted fragments, please

Comment: why are you specifying natheight and natwidth ? this obscures the real size of the image and so latex has no chance to position it correctly. Also you ask for the image to be centred  but you have `width=1\textwidth` so left, right or centred alignment is the same thing as you are forcing the image to span the entire page

Comment: for any new documents it is much better to use a standard input encoding such as utf8 or latin1 rather than the non standard ansinew

Answer (score 4):

If you specify the original size of the image with `natwidth` and `natheight` keys then latex will believe that is the size of the image, but as the image is not that size all positioning calculations will be incorrect.

the following example shows a centred image (note that this is a complete document, your fragments are incomplete and reference files that are not available which makes it hard to see the issue)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{a centred image}
\end{figure}

\noindent X\dotfill X % just to see the page width

\end{document}
```